# Using Angular $http in a service to fire on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angularjs-scope

I am currently using Angular 1.3.14 and I would like to make an request using $http whenever a link is clicked. I am trying to place the $http request in a service so it's not bound to any one controller and can be accessed by multiple controllers. I've created two functions sayHello() and getData(). I want each one to console.log when clicked. Only the sayHello() function does, but not the getData() function.. Here's what I don't understand.

1. Why does the $http request fire on load, and not on click whereas the sayHello function works perfectly?
2. How can I modify my code so it works as intended?

   ```
   <p><a href="#" ng-click="getData()">Console Log Our Data</a></p>
   <p>
     <a href="#" ng-click="sayHello()">Console Log The Word "Hello"</a></p>
   ```

   ```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

   .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, dataService){

   $scope.sayHello = dataService.sayHello;

   $scope.getData = dataService.getData(function(response){
           $scope.myData = response.data;
       console.log($scope.myData);
       });
   })
   .service('dataService', function($http){

   this.getData = function(callback){
         $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
           .then(callback);
       }

     this.sayHello = function(){
       console.log("Hello!");
     }


   });
   ```

Codepen for reference http://codepen.io/benweiser/pen/remvvo/

Answer (score 2):

That's because `$scope.getData` is equal to undefined when it should be a function

```
$scope.getData = function () {
  dataService.getData(function(response) {
     $scope.myData = response.data
     console.log($scope.myData)
  })
}
```

---

Update: You can send parameters either from the call to the method or from the method itself, suppose you have the following input

```
<input ng-model="name">
```

Then you can use the send the value and use it in your service as follows

```
<a ng-click="getData(name)">get data</a>

$scope.getData = function (name) {
  dataService.getData(name)
     .then(function (response) { ... })
}
```

Or using it directly in the controller

```
<a ng-click="getData()">get data</a>

$scope.getData = function () {
  dataService.getData($scope.name)
     .then(function (response) { ... })
}
```

Note that both assume that `dataService.getData()` returns a promise instead of passing the callback so you'd also need to do the following on your service if you want to code it like above

```
this.getData = function (name) {
  // do something with name
  return $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + name)
}
```

You should read more on Promises vs callbacks and how you can take advantage of them :)

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. I would upvote, but don't have credentials. Is it possible for me to pass parameters using this method? Let's say I want to get data from ng-model in an input and pass that through the URL in the service? Or is this a better use case for a controller? example http://get_this_url.com/content.PARAMSFROMMODELHERE.json ?

Comment: Answer updated, you should keep on reading the fundamentals @BenWeiser, https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

```
$scope.getData = dataService.getData(function(response){
    $scope.myData = response.data;
    console.log($scope.myData);
 });
```

})

dataService.getData get executed immediately. As a result, $scope.getData is set to a promise instead of a function you intent to bind to ng-click

change this line $scope.getData = dataService.getData to the following which will actually set a function with callback to $scope.getData

```
$scope.getData = dataService.getData.bind(this, function(response) {
    $scope.myData = response.data;
    console.log($scope.myData);
});
```

Comment: Any advantages or disadvantages to this as opposed to the Maurcio's method?

Comment: `this.getData` in the OP example returns undefined, not a promise

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing something like this.  Should be easy to apply to your code above

```
//in your factory
app.factory('dataFactory',function($http){

    factory = {};

    //get data
    factory.getData = function(obj){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/postsn'
        })
    };

    return factory
}); 

//in your controller
app.controller(someCtrl,function($scope,dataFactory){

  dataFactory.getData().then(function(data){
      console.log('This will be your data: ', data)
  })

})
```

Comment: Thank you I don't quite yet understand factories I am going to do have to hit the docs to wrap my head around that vs a service.

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax query was being made when controller was first loading. Your bind with "getData" wasn't with a function, but with an ajax call, and that was why it was not triggered.

This refactor works on codepen:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, dataService){

    $scope.sayHello = dataService.sayHello;

    $scope.getData = function(){
    dataService.getData().then(
        function(response){
            $scope.myData = response.data;
                console.log($scope.myData);
            }
        );
    }
})

.service('dataService', function($http){

    this.getData = function(callback){
        return $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    }

    this.sayHello = function(){
        console.log("Hello!");
    }

});
```

Main updates:

1. $scope.getData is binded to a function, not an Ajax call/promise
2. Promise is outside the service (better solutions are welcome :-) ).
3. dataService.getData is called as a function. (Did't work in other way).